# backbone:difference between default property and property defined in options hash

Tags: backbone.js

Please say, what is the difference between declaring a property on defaults (like name:'dflt name') and declaring a property on outside defaults (like name:'name prop'). Also in initialize function when i tried to change the props value its not changing (like this.name = "Mr."+this.name;). Please see the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
        arrModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                name:'dflt name'                    
            },              
            name:'name prop',
            initialize:function(){
                this.name = "Mr."+this.name;
                console.log("init", this.name) // this is printing raj not Mr.raj
            }
        })
        m = new arrModel({
            name:'raj',
            std:2
        });
        console.log(m.attributes)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference the name attribute, you need to say something like this.get('name') as this method navigates into the attributes hash where attributes are stored.

The defaults hash is used to seed the default attributes hash in the model.  This is useful if you do not pass in attributes with you create a new model instance.  Or, if certain values have defaults and you'd rather not pass those in everytime you do a create.

To change an attribute, you use the set method.  To change the name, you would have to do something like this:

```
this.set({name: 'some new name'});
```

or

```
this.set({name: 'some new name'}, {silent: true});
```

where the former call would run the validation and the latter call would bypass validation.

Comment: Thanks Bill Eisenhauer for the answer. One up vote for your kind effort :-).